# Reading a URL to html file

Tags: html, url

txt file containing urls that need to be open and display the contents in a 4x4 board in an html file. Having some trouble with this as I am new too html. the first board reads the words and the second is supposed to display the pictures in a randomized order.

this is the .text file

```
A,ant   
B,bear
C,cat
D,dog
E,elephant
F,fox
G,goat
H,horse
I, iguana
J, Jaguar 
K,kangaroo
L, lion
M,monkey
N,newt
O,ostrich
P,penguin
A,http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/470x370/ant8.jpg  
B,http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/470x370/bear5.jpg
C,http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/470x370/cat1.jpg
D, http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/470x370/dog5.jpg
E, http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/470x370/african_elephant.jpg
F, http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/470x370/fox.jpg
G,goat, http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/470x370/goat.jpg
H, http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/470x370/horse8.jpg
I, http://www.vivanatura.org/Iguana_iguana_juv1.jpg
J, http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Jaguar.jpg/800px-Jaguar.jpg
K,http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/005/cache/gray-kangaroo_554_600x450.jpg
L, http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg/800px-Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg
M,http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Crab-eating_Macaque_tree.jpg http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Notophthalmus_viridescensPCCA20040816-3983A.jpg
O,http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/Ostriches_cape_point_cropped.jpg
P,http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Pygoscelis_papua.jpg
```

heres what i have so far, any hep would be much appreciated.

```
/*Muhammed Motala
 * ics 240 prof. Jasthi
 * THis program reads lines from a pre-existing text files and writes the
 *  contents to an HTMl file, while putting each line of code into a box forming two 4x4 board's.  
 */


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TicTacTwice {

   public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {    

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Muhammed/Documents/Tic_Tac_Twice/tic_tac_twice2.txt"));
     BufferedWriter output = null;
     String myLine = null;
     String [] words = new String[100];
     int counter = 0;
     int counter1 = 0;
     boolean run  = true;

          do {

            try {

                  while(sc.hasNextLine()) {    //reads each line in the txt file


                    String product = sc.nextLine();
                    myLine = product;

                    if (product.contains(" ")) {    // if the line contains a space

                        String[] array1 = product.split(" ");  // if contains space add to array
                        words[counter] = array1[1];
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if (product.contains("http://")) {

                            String [] array1 = product.split(",");
                            words[counter] = array1[1];
                            counter++;
                            System.out.println(array1[1]);


                    }
                    else if (product.contains(",")) {  // if contains comma split into separate array

                        String [] array1 = product.split(",");
                        words[counter] = array1[1];
                        counter++;

                    }

                  }

                sc.close();

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/Users/Muhammed/Documents/tic_tac_twice.html");
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write("<html");              // html code upon writing of the file
                    bw.write("<head>");
                    bw.write("<table>");
                    bw.write("<h1> TICK TAC TWICE <h1>");
                    bw.write("<h1> Board 1 <h1>");
                    bw.write("</table>");
                    bw.write("</head>");
                    bw.write("<body>");
                    bw.write("<style>table, th, td{border:1px solid black;padding:5px}"
                            + "table{border-spacing:15px}</style>");
                    bw.write("<table style=width:300px>");


                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  // array to create board1 and 
                                                  // populate with the read in lines

                            bw.write("<tr>");

                        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                            bw.write("<td>");
                            bw.write(words[counter1]);
                            counter1++;
                            bw.write("</td>");

                        }

                        bw.write("<tr>");
                    }
                        bw.write("<style>table, th, td{border:1px solid black;padding:5px}"
                                + "table{border-spacing:15px}</style>");
                        bw.write("<table style=width:300px>");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   // creates board 2 and populates with 
                                                    // words that are stored in array

                                bw.write("<tr>");

                            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                                bw.write("<td>");
                                bw.write(words[counter1]);
                                bw.write("<td><img src=\"" + words[counter] + 
                                        "\" alt=\"some_text\"width=200 height=200></img>");
                                counter1++;
                                bw.write("</td>");


                            }

                            bw.write("<tr>");
                    }
                bw.write("<h1> Board 2 <h1>");  
                bw.write("</body>");
                bw.write("</html>");
                bw.close();

                run = false;

             }
                catch (Exception e) {       // exception handler
                    System.out.print(e.toString());
                }
            } 
            while(run);

    }
}
```

Comment: it's the java code you need help on or html?

Comment: well I need help on the randomization of the second board and also how to display the images in the second board